# Entity Framework - Comparing items

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, comparison

I am currently a little bit stuck and need to have some advice on how to proceed. I have the following setup:

- Two databases, one Ingres, the other one MSSQL
- I take a subset of data from the Ingres database (which is a mess), bring it into a (much more) normalized form and store it in the MSSQL database for further use.
- I get the data items from the Ingres DB through a normal DataReader and store the items in the MSSQL database using the Entity Framework
- So far, this basically works (jey!)

The database model (in the MSSQL DB) consists of 5 tables, whereas one table is the main table (Articles) and the other tables (Prices, Batches, ...) relate to that table (mostly through the Article number which is a primary key).

Now we're talking about 35k articles where each article has many batches and so on. This has become a problem when I update the full table each time (basically what I do is that I TRUNCATE the tables and recreate the whole dataset). This takes (on a very slow server) approx. 5-10 minutes (even after some modifications to the Entity Framework defaults).
Since the dataset must be consistent, the table is basically locked through that timeframe which is a no-go.

I would like to switch to a continuous update method where the checking and modification of data is performed continuously in the background.

Basically the only idea I could come up with was to go through all the items manually and check if any property of the item has changed. If it did (or if it is new) I would manually modify the property.

Do any of you know of a better way how this could be handled? What would be the best way to perform this comparison since I would like to compare each article (with all its dependencies) to the one from the other database. Is there some automated method?

Comment: Thanks for down-voting, at least a reason would be nice ...

Answer (score 0):

If Ingres supports Triggers, then put triggers on the ingres tables which write out the new values to a new table (one per original table) also putting a flag on the change table to indicate whether it was an insert, update, or delete. Include a timestamp on the change table as well.

Then at whatever interval is appropriate (or continuously), read each change from the change table and apply it to the MSSQL table and then delete the change row.

It will probably be a bit more complex than that, but that basic technique seems like a good approach to me.

Comment: Thought about that, but the only access I have to the Ingres DB is reading (no writing or triggers or anything ...)

Comment: That gives you a real problem, then. Given Ingres has been out of business for many many years, I assume that the suppliers of the Ingres system are not available? Does the customer have a DBA with access to change the DB? Or is the customer totally unwilling to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, for the moment the database is "don't touch this at all or die" :(.

Comment: I can sort of understand that. I used Ingres for a few years in the early '90s and it could do all sorts of supprising things, but I don't remember the details now. It might be worth getting hold of a manual and seeing if there is anything relatively unintrusive which might help, a possible argument being that if there is something it would be lighter than the full selects you're currently running. Other than that, I don't see any alternative to your current full-recreate strategy - unless you can intercept the data going to Ingres before it gets there (from a Web Site possibly). Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah, the funniest I found was that your results when there is a trailing space might be all kinds of stupid. Thanks anyway for your input.